# Make a stepper motor move

Tags: stepper

I am at the moment trying to make a bipolar stepper motor move. 
I am interfacing it through a control board, which takes the input `Step`, `Dir`, `En`, and 5V.

I am providing those input signal via an Arduino, but can't get the damn thing to move. all it does it move a step forward and backwards, like it being stuck or and tries to wiggle out of something.. What could the reason be..

Here is the Code:

```
#include "stepper_motor.h"
int max_step = 200;
stepper_motor::stepper_motor()
{
  pinMode(BUILTIN_LED,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(step_pin,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dir_pin,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(en_pin,OUTPUT);

  alive_bool = true;
  position_bool = false;
  step_count = 0;
}

void stepper_motor::step_pwm()
{

  if(position_bool==true)
  {
    //Dir pin low 
    digitalWrite(step_pin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(dir_pin,LOW);
    digitalWrite(en_pin,LOW);

    delay(0.005);

    digitalWrite(step_pin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(dir_pin,LOW);
    digitalWrite(en_pin,HIGH);

    delay(0.005);

    int step = 0;
    while(step < max_step)
    {
      digitalWrite(step_pin,HIGH);
      delay(1);
      digitalWrite(step_pin,LOW);
      delay(1);
    }

    //digitalWrite(en_pin,LOW);
    //position_bool = false;
  }
  else
  {
    //Dir pin high 
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(step_pin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(dir_pin,LOW);
    digitalWrite(en_pin,LOW);

    delay(0.005);

    digitalWrite(step_pin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(dir_pin,LOW);
    digitalWrite(en_pin,HIGH);

    delay(0.005);

    digitalWrite(step_pin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(dir_pin,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(en_pin,HIGH);

    int step = 0;
    while(step < max_step)
    {
      digitalWrite(step_pin,HIGH);
      delay(1);
      digitalWrite(step_pin,LOW);
      delay(1);
    }

    //digitalWrite(en_pin,LOW);
    //position_bool = true;
  }



}
```

Updated step_pwm():

```
void stepper_motor::step_pwm()
{
    //Start -  En Low , DIR HIGH, STEP high
    //init configuration!
    digitalWrite(step_pin, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(dir_pin,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(en_pin,LOW); // Previous LOW

    delay(0.005);

    //T1-  En HIGH , DIR HIGH, STEP HIGH
    //Enable high
    //digitalWrite(step_pin, HIGH);
    //digitalWrite(dir_pin,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(en_pin,HIGH);

    delay(0.005);

    //T2-  En HIGH , DIR low, STEP HIGH
    //Direction choosen
    //digitalWrite(step_pin, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(dir_pin,LOW);
    //digitalWrite(en_pin,HIGH);

    delay(0.005);
    //T2-  En HIGH , DIR low, STEP HIGH
    //STEP  step between low and high with 2.5µs between

    while(1)
    {
      digitalWrite(step_pin,LOW);
      delay(2.5);
      digitalWrite(step_pin,HIGH);
      delay(2.5);
    }

}
```

The control board i am using is a [ST330-v3](http://www.sainsmart.com/zen/documents/20-019-201/ST330%20%20Stepper%20Motor%20Driver%20Board%20User%20Manual.pdf) 
The motor i am using is [this one](https://www.orientalmotor.com.sg/products/st/list/detail/?product_name=PK244-01A&brand_tbl_code=ST&series_code=G000&type_code=Unipolar%206%20lead%20wires&type=Standard%20Type)
here is a little block diagram of how things are connected.

[image]

Comment: Your voltage is too low.

Comment: Its getting 12 volt, as required by the motor? and plenty of amp.. it is rated 1.2 A but the control board is capable of giving it 3 amp

Comment: You have the stepper connected wrong? Post the schematic.

Comment: I've posted an image of how things are connected.. 
I suspect it could have something to do with common ground?

Comment: It cannot be the common ground. I am only providing one ground signal... So it should not cause a problem.

Comment: "I am only providing one ground signal... So it should not cause a problem." No, that is your problem. You need to tie the Arduino ground to the driver board as well. As it stands, the driver has no way of knowing whether your inputs are high or low. The 5 volt connection does not suffice. In fact, the failure to provide a ground means that all the driver logic is unpowered. Consider this - would you expect your Arduino to work if you only connected its 5V, and not the ground?

Comment: So... you suggesting connect the negative terminal of the power with ground terminal of the arduino? Sorry for asking such a stupid question.. I am very much a noob when it comes to electronics.. Not at all my strong suit..

Comment: Doing above didn't not help..

Comment: Verify continuity in the two motor coils (multimeter). Reconnect and replace the Arduino with a debounced pushbutton driving the step input and tie EN and DIR to active and an arbitrary level respectively. Verify the voltages change across the coils sequentially.

Comment: Ok.. I will post an update code.. I made the motor move, but  only by removing the enable signal.  I accidentally pulled it out of the arduino and the system began to move. Then tried to remove the enable pin, and it changed direction.  But i can't codewise change the direction.. I guess this concludes that there isn't any wiring problem but the problem relies in the code..

Comment: Maybe your impression of which pin is enable and which is direction is swapped.  Best recheck everything with the most authoritative source documentation.  If the board documentation isn't great, get the IC data sheet and trace the connections to it.

Comment: I am using a wemos d1 mini. 
The pin_mapping comes from this .h file 
https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/variants/d1_mini/pins_arduino.h#L49-L61

If the mapping made above is incorrect, then would it explain alot of things

Comment: "am providing those input signal via a **arduino**" - "I am using a wemos d1 mini" ???

Comment: Well... It should not matter since i am using the arduino library.. So there implementation should still be there.

Comment: But the d1 mini uses an ESP8266 which has 3.3V GPIO. You are powering the opto-couplers with +5V and the ESP8266 is pulling down from +3.3V to its ground, so the optocouplers are getting 1.7V (5V-3.3V) when the GPIO outputs are high. Since the infrared LED in the optocoupler only needs 1.1V to turn on, there is a chance it will stay turned on enough to prevent the high signal from being transferred. This might explain why you had to disconnect the EN signal (yes, disconnected is same as high on the ST330 - bad design!)

Comment: wauw... That sound like something that could make sense.. 
Anyway can I still could use the board someway, or would I have to use an arduino uno or something like that?

Comment: an uno does the same thing..

Comment: I am NOT sure  at all what what the solution is.. The ST330 seem like a bad design..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must set EN BEFORE you set DIR.  The datasheet says EN must be high for at least 5 microseconds before you set DIR.  You should probably just set EN high when your program starts, then not fool with it until your program ends.

The next thing is that I don't see you incrementing the variable "step" anywhere.  So, if you did get the stepper to turn, it wouldn't stop.

---

The updated code looks like it ought to work.

You should use DelayMicroseconds instead of Delay(0.005) though.  Delay takes an integer instead of a decimal value, so you won't get what you expect.  Curse the Arduino IDE for not throwing a fit when pass a float for an int.

---

It looks like anything working properly is purely luck.  The board you are using(NOT an Arduino) uses 3.3V logic levels.  The ST330 says a high must be at least 4V, so if it reacts to your control signals at all it is just luck.

The 8266 outputs are rated for 12mA, the ST330 inputs need about 20mA, so you are over doing it.  The 8266 might put up with, and might just die on you.

You might be able to drive the ST330 by switching the mode of the pins.

Low would be "set pin to mode output and set low."

A high would be "set mode input."

Input mode leaves the pin floating, which the ST330 will interpret as a high.

Other than that, you could use NPN transistors to drive the ST330 inputs, then invert your output signals.

The NPN would invert your signal (a high becomes a low) so you would have to set an output to low to get a high going into the ST330.

---

You can use NPN transistors like this to drive the ST330:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPzYWz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Setting the  GPIO from the ESP8266 to high would cause a low on the ST330 input.

Setting the GPIO pin to low would cause a high on the ST330 input.

This is the solution I would prefer if I needed to use the ESP8266 with the ST330.

---

If you'd like to try a purely software solution, then do this:

1. To send a low to the ST330 input, set the GPIO to pin mode output and set the output to low. (pinMode(step_pin,INPUT) then DigitalWrite(step_pin,LOW))
2. To send a high to the ST330 input, set the pin mode to INPUT (pinMode(step_pin,INPUT)

When the GPIO pin is in input mode, it floats.  It doesn't have a voltage level of its own - it acts like it is disconnected.

If that works, I'd still prefer to use the transistors.

---

You can avoid all of this using the UNO.  It has 5V logic levels on the outputs.

Comment: It this based on the updated code or the prior?

Comment: The step variable is missing that is right, and it turned yes it didn't stop.  but the direction cannot be coded. what the mean by EN set before DIR is set.. isn't the case?

Comment: The ST330 has opto-couplers that require connection to +5V and signal inputs only ('yin and yang' interface!). To maintain the isolation barrier the Arduino ground and ST330 ground should **not** be connected together.

Comment: @BruceAbbott: I missed that while looking at the timing diagrams.  I'll change that part.

Comment: @CarltonBanks:  Based on the original code.  I'll take a look at what you've changed.

Comment: I understand the changes.. But is it what you had i mind..

I still have an issue with the thing only running when I use delay() and not delayMicroseconds(). The motor outputs a high pitch noise.

Comment: The high partand the low part of the pulse must each be at least 2.5 microseconds long.  The force the motor can generate is proportional to the pulse length.  Shorter is weaker.  If the pulses are too short, the motor can't move.  A quick look around the internet shows typical pulse rates in milliseconds range rather than in microseconds.

Comment: The change you made is pretty much what I meant.

Comment: Its just stated in the datasheet. But as mentioned the function only works with delay and not delayMicroseconds.

Comment: If you use DelayMicroseconds, then you would need a value of 2500 to get 2.5 milliseconds.

Comment: Regarding to your update..what do mean by switching of the pins? Could i use a uno instead? or what is the solution here?

Comment: And what is the solution you refer to.. I mean is an arduino uno able to provide this output

Comment: Are you sure about the input current... VM input current = 16 mA as max..

Comment: typical being 10 mA

Comment: Thanks for the last one.. 
I have an uno lying around, and if everything would work fine with the uno.. I would just transfer the code from the ESP to the uno..

Comment: Uno  made it work.. 

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

This is problematic:

```
 delay(0.005);
```

The Arduino delay() function takes an `unsigned long` as an input, which is an integer rather than floating point type.  As a result, the argument you pass to it will be treated as zero.  Depending on how delay() is implemented this will result in either no delay (beyond overhead), or a minimum that may be longer than you intended.

Of course you now seem to only be running this code once, and then going into an unending loop which uses a 2.5 ms delay that will, for the same reason, be more of a 2ms delay.

Comment: I am not sure i understand the answer.. I myself have wonderes why it works with the delay() and not delayMicroseconds() it seems a bit of.

Comment: You need to take time to understand the difference between integer and floating point types, otherwise any success will be little more than luck.

Comment: Ohh.. i understand the difference.. The only reason why i know it works is as you mention yourself. The code overhead. running delay(0) or delay(0.005) takes aprox. 12 µs which would have fulfilled the minimum required timeslot.